# ip address array validation in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation, ip

I want to know how to do ip address array validation in codeigniter. I have an array containing of certain ip addresses.

```
     Consider texbox which is generated dynamically with name=ip[] and id auto increments like ip1 ip2......


 if for eg: $ip=$this->input->post('ip'); 
 $ip[0] =1.1.1.1, $ip[1]=2.2.2.2, $ip[2]=3.3.3.3
```

how can i validate the ip addresses. I tried using the following:

```
 for ($i = $ip[0]; $i <= end($ip); $i++) {
                    if (!$this->input->valid_ip($i)) {
                        echo " Not a valid IP address";}}
```

It works fine when using close ip ranges like 2.2.2.2, 2.2.2.3, 2.2.2.4 etc: or a single ip address. but when the input is say 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3, 4.4.4.4 it lags. similarily it also lags when 2 ips are valid but if the third is a 'text' it lags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem,

```
    foreach($ip as $value){
       if (!$this->input->valid_ip($value)) {
       echo " <script>alert('Not a valid IP address');</script>";}}
```